# How to solve $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{2^{\ln{x}}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, power-series

I am trying to determine whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/2^{\ln{n}}$ converges or diverges. My calculus book tells me to use the integral test. The steps:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{2^{\ln{x}}} = 
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{2^{\ln{x}}} = 
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^u \, du}{2^u} = 
\lim_{b \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\ln{\frac{e}{2}}} \left(\left(\frac{e}{2}\right)^b-1\right) = \infty$$

How did they change the lower limit of the integral to zero? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: $$2^{\ln n}=e^{\ln 2\cdot\ln n}=n^{\ln 2},$$ so $$\frac1{2^{\ln n}}>\frac1n.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Is there an easier way to do this"

Yes. Multiple, First of all as Thomas said , $2^{\ln(n)}=n^{\ln(2)}$ and $\displaystyle\sum \frac{1}{n^{p}}$ converges iff $p>1$ and $\ln(2)\approx 0.693<1$ .

Also, instead of using Integral test, you can opt for [Cauchy Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) , i.e. if $a_{n}$ is a non-increasing positive sequence then $\sum_{n} a_{n}$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n}2^{n}a_{2^{n}}$ converges. This is a useful technique to get rid of the log.

So you have $\displaystyle\sum_{n}\frac{2^{n}}{2^{\ln(2^{n})}}=\sum_{n}\frac{2^{n}}{2^{n\ln(2)}} =\sum_{n}2^{n(1-\ln(2))}$ which obviously diverges as the terms are unbounded and hence so does the original series.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much! This helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I believe a typo was made. In moving to the integral with $u$, they seem to use the substitution $u=\ln(x)$, but as $x \to 0$, $u \to -\infty$, not $0$.

I imagine they intended to have your second integral as starting at $1$, as a result, in line with typical statements of the integral test.

*Edit:* Moreover, more obviously, the first equality does not hold at all, and this is obvious from the graph of the function.

Comment: In the book, they substituted $u = ln(x)$, $x = e^u$, and $dx = e^udu$

Comment: Which is what I stated, yes.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for letting me know.